# How can I recover mongo / minimongo DB data from the browser within a meteor app?

Tags: mongodb, google-chrome, console, meteor

So I have a meteor app and someone on another client deleted a bunch of data out of it. The data no longer lives on the server but it appears that DDP has not pushed the changes to my client (it was on a sleeping laptop and I took the internet connection down before I woke it back up).

The question is how can I recover as much of the servers DB from the minimongo instance that lives in the browser?

Is there any other technique that might work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

quick and dirty would be something like:

```
console.log(JSON.stringify(YourCollection.find({}).fetch()));
```

that will at least get you the json data for each collection - in theory you can then take that string and reload the database from the client at a later point